# Expire/delete documents from Mongo based on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that it is possible to create a TTL index which will delete all data indexes after e.g. 60 minutes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

I want to implement a feature which will delete data based on passing or failing a condition. For example:

```
user = new mongoose.Schema ({
  isAuthenticated: Boolean
})
```

If a user does not authenticate within 24 hours lets delete him from database - I come from SQL Server background and haven't got much experience with Mongo. How would I do that? Any ideas? Stored procs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no job management in mongoDB, you have to do it client side.